# Using flickr justify algorithm for my website for viewing images

Tags: jquery, layout, flickr, justify

I saw this code here on stackoverflow that gives a view similar to the justify view that flickr gives with it's images. I would like to use a similar view for my images however I am unsure of how to procede as the example given uses flickr's api to stream the images.

I would like to know how to use my own images dynamically loaded using cakephp or regular php.

Link to stackoverflow topic: [How to build a Flickr Justified View like using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736135/how-to-build-a-flickr-justified-view-like-using-jquery)

Link to example code: http://jsbin.com/upinek/3/edit

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? The example code is just from someone else's blog post. You could write a php script which uses your own images and outputs json with the same structure as Flickr's api. Then just replace the `$.getJSON` url from the script with your script's url.

Comment: Yes it is from someone else's site as was stated in what I wrote. I am not sure where to start with creating such a structure as flickr's api which is why I asked the question in the first place.

I have been searching and I am still searching but any link to any reference or other further help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099449/creating-a-rest-api-with-cakephp and you'll need to grab some of Flickr's json so you can copy the structure.

Comment: Went through the code, what edit would be needed to do this without an api? Checked with my other guys and they don't want to go through creating an api for it.

We would essentially be pulling image link and information from a database.

Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I wrote a jQuery plugin to do it some time back - https://github.com/kalyan02/flowr-js